# После обновления системы не стартует postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Добрый день, проблема такая, обновил Ubuntu с 14.04 до 16.04, как всегда все хороше, НО!
за одно обновился и postgresql с 9.5.x до 9.5.y и перестал запускаться, точнее валится при запуске, логи:
/etc/syslog

```
Sep  9 07:34:20 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main...
Sep  9 07:34:23 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: PID file /var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Sep  9 07:35:51 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Sep  9 07:35:51 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 9.5-main.
Sep  9 07:35:51 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep  9 07:35:51 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: postgresql@9.5-main.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Sep  9 07:35:51 ip-172-31-60-94 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

Система пытается запустить PostgreSQL, но не вкладывается в таймаут (судя по всему 30 сек.) и валится.
Вопрос, как увеличить таймаут запуска службы, на пример в MySQL есть опция

```
service_startup_timeout=900
```

может и в PostgreSQL  есть что то подобное?

Comment: *Вопрос, как увеличить таймаут запуска службы* -- а это, думаете, поможет?

Answer (score 2):

согласно написанному [здесь](http://charlesnagy.info/it/postgresql/postgresql-server-fails-to-start-in-recovery-with-systemd) по поводу аналогичной ошибки, надо заменить `-w` на `-W` в «сервисном» файле `/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.5.service` в строке:

```
ExecStart=/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/pg_ctl start -D ${PGDATA} -s -w -t 300
```

после чего перезагрузить *systemd*:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

и запустить *postgresql*:

```
$ sudo serrvice postgresql-9.5 start
```